Newbie - MDADM "inactive" or "active, FAILED, Not Started"

I'm extremely new to Linux and MDADM... So I hope this question is not totally trivial !
I am now completely blocked :-( !
I was in the middle of a Plex movie (read from a shared folder, which is from a RAID MDADM 10 disks array).
... suddenly, all was in error.
A first surprise to me is that I was sure I had RAID 5, but everywhere it is mentioned RAID 6 in my System.
I'm running 
/ Ubuntu Linux 24.04 
/ Linux 6.10.6-061006-generic on x86_64 
/ Processor information    11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11600K @ 3.90GHz, 12 cores
Using headerless server, so installed Webmin : 
Webmin version 2.202
Here are my detailed commands and results :

sudo mdadm --examine --scan :
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=b2a7da9c:775a4913:e2d2c701:fe1caf62 name=ubuntuplex:0
I was surprised about the '/' between the md and the 0. 
And here is what I have in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf :
ARRAY /dev/md0  metadata=1.2 UUID=b2a7da9c:775a4913:e2d2c701:fe1caf62 name=ubuntuplex:0

And here what is in my /etc/fstab :
/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nobootwait,nofail,discard 0 0


sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 :
Resulting in :
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid6
  Total Devices : 11
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive 
Working Devices : 11

           Name : ubuntuplex:0
           UUID : b2a7da9c:775a4913:e2d2c701:fe1caf62
         Events : 462412

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

   -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
   -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
   -       8      176        -        /dev/sdl
   -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
   -       8      144        -        /dev/sdj
   -       8      112        -        /dev/sdh
   -       8       80        -        /dev/sdf
   -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
   -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
   -       8      160        -        /dev/sdk
   -       8       96        -        /dev/sdg




       Until this stage, status is INACTIVE. 


When I then tried sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0 which resulted in :
mdadm: failed to start array /dev/md/0: Input/output error
I repeated sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 which this time gave :

/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Nov 30 12:18:58 2023
        Raid Level : raid6
     Used Dev Size : 1953382400 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 10
     Total Devices : 9
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Aug 23 21:03:41 2024
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started 
    Active Devices : 9
   Working Devices : 9
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : unknown

              Name : ubuntuplex:0
              UUID : b2a7da9c:775a4913:e2d2c701:fe1caf62
            Events : 462412

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed
       -       0        0        3      removed
       -       0        0        4      removed
       -       0        0        5      removed
       -       0        0        6      removed
       -       0        0        7      removed
       -       0        0        8      removed
       -       0        0        9      removed

       -       8       64        4      sync   /dev/sde
       -       8       32        3      sync   /dev/sdc
       -       8      176        9      sync   /dev/sdl
       -       8        0        0      sync   /dev/sda
       -       8      144        6      sync   /dev/sdj
       -       8      112        7      sync   /dev/sdh
       -       8       48        2      sync   /dev/sdd
       -       8       16        1      sync   /dev/sdb
       -       8      160        8      sync   /dev/sdk

 
 4. Because I see many people sharing the `sudo fdisk -l` , here is my result (it is very long) :
Disk /dev/loop0: 10.09 MiB, 10575872 bytes, 20656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 10.08 MiB, 10571776 bytes, 20648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 103.99 MiB, 109043712 bytes, 212976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 104.19 MiB, 109252608 bytes, 213384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 74.24 MiB, 77848576 bytes, 152048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 74.27 MiB, 77881344 bytes, 152112 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 104.13 MiB, 109182976 bytes, 213248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 104.13 MiB, 109182976 bytes, 213248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdi: 489.05 GiB, 525112713216 bytes, 1025610768 sectors
Disk model: Crucial_CT525MX3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8F8595EE-85AD-49A5-A4CD-7CD9539BB703

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdi1       2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdi2     206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdi3     239616  122882047 122642432  58.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdi4  122882048  227330047 104448000  49.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdi5  227330048 1025609727 798279680 380.6G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdh: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdg: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdc4f655d


Disk /dev/sdj: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x453f2fe0

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdj1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdk: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdl: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 38.73 MiB, 40615936 bytes, 79328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 38.83 MiB, 40714240 bytes, 79520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

I have upgraded OS to 24.04, and kernel to 6.10.6-061006-generic on x86_64. But, of course, nothing about MDADM changed... Please help me out here... Would be really great :-)
